# MySQL-inserted custom taxonomy term lead to 404, flush rewrites doesn't help

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, terms, 404-error

I import my custom terms from a desktop program using MySQL queries. But all the terms lead me to a 404 page. I tried flushing rewrites many times, it didn't help. It only helps when I save individual terms at https://[mysite]/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=store-category&tag_ID=[int ID]

I create my custom taxonomy like this

```
$labels = some labels
$args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => false,
        'rewrite'                    => true
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'store-category', array( 'tdlrm_store_item' ), $args );
```

Then I insert my terms into my database:

```
//repeated for each term
//insert term into wp_terms
$wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix.'terms', array(
    'name' => $import_group['name'],
    'slug' => $import_group['slug']
));

//get the inserted term id
$term_id = $wpdb->insert_id;

//insert the term's id from my program
$wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix.'termmeta',array(
   'term_id' => $term_id,
   'meta_key' => 'import_id',
   'meta_value' => $import_group['id']
));

//connect to taxonomy: store-category
$wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix.'term_taxonomy',array(
   'term_taxonomy_id' => $term_id,
   'term_id' => $term_id,
   'taxonomy' => 'store-category',
   'parent' => 0 //I have another function that inserts child items 
));
```

That's it. I've got a term in `wp_terms`, it's connected to taxonomy in `wp_term_taxonomy`.

Then, each product has its $import_group['id'], I just look for it in meta_value in `wp_termmeta` and insert the returned term_id as the term_taxonomy_id in `wp_terms_relationships`.

Looks like I've got everything covered, but when I go to [site root]/store-category/[term-slug]/, it leads me to a 404 page. What am I doing wrong? Is there any other place I have to insert term related data to? wp_options?

Flushing rewrite rules does not help (tried many times). Also, the number of posts shown under each of the terms is 0 (wrong), maybe this is related. Also, when I go to a term's wp-admin page and save it, this fixes the 404 issue for this term. But I can't do it manually, too many terms.

I've read [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/196657/flush-rewrite-rules-doesnt-flush-them-still-got-404), [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175452/custom-post-type-single-permalink-throws-a-404-error) and similar questions but all the answers seem to be variants of 'try to flush rewrites again', which I did.

---

Oh, and I've just noticed. The same happens with individual posts: 404 until I refresh their term.

---

I tried deleting data from rewrite_rules in wp_options too, no use.

---

I changed 'rewrite' => true to 'rewrite' => false, and I don't get 404 page now, but still no idea how to fix the issue with rewrite turned on.

All irrelevant plugins are deactivated

Comment: Why didn't you use [`wp_insert_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/) and [`add_term_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_term_meta/)?

Comment: because I batch import data from xml files that come in http requests, and it was more convinient for me to do it this way in this case. one of the reasons is that it's a function file inside a plugin, and I need to manually include files like wp-includes/taxonomy.php in it for wp_insert_term() to work. $wpdb was already used in the file, so it was more convinient to use it for all the tasks. Maybe it was something else, too

Anyway, it doesn't matter. I've found out it applies even to the 'store-category terms I manually create in wp-admin. They give me a 404 page too

Comment: Well, if the import code/function is in a WordPress site, then those two functions I mentioned would always be ready in an active plugin. So why do you need to manually load the core WordPress files; how the function file is being loaded? And using those two functions might not going to fix the permalinks issue, but your code will be much simpler.

Comment: Sally, thank you for your question. I am well aware of the two functions and use them where needed, but not in this case. It has to do with my plugin's file structure and the task.

Comment: One thing is MySQL transactions.

Comment: Fine then. But if you could load the `$wpdb` API, then I don't think there's a harm in loading the taxonomy/term APIs - at the very least, to check if creating the term using `wp_insert_term()` still results in the 404 error (on the term page/archive) or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EUREKA!

My taxonomy name is 'store-category'. When i used 'rewrite' = true or 'rewrite' = array('slug' => 'category') it was giving me a 404 error. When I changed it to 'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'group') the problem just went away!

So, the problem turned out to be a rewrite conflict. WordPress had been looking for my store-categories within *categories*, hence the 404 error.

No idea how 'store-category' fits in (when rewrite is just set true), but obviously it caused the same problem.

So, **SOLUTION: don't use slugs that match default WP slugs; try changing your slug to something else**.